# Image Source not refreshing after Editing Binding Source

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have an `Image` in my xaml. That `Image` gets its source from a `Converter`. When a click on this image happens it changes the property of the binding source.

What doesn't happen is that the image changes it's source instantly, but if I switch the `DataContext` of the parent and then switch back to the changed item, it displays just fine.

The xaml:

```
<conv:BoolImageConverter x:Key="MarkiertImageConverter"/>
[...]
<Border x:Name="maBorder"
        DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=myACB, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}">
  <Grid>
    [...]
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
      [...]
      <Image x:Name="favImage"
             [...]
             Source="{Binding Markiert, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource MarkiertImageConverter}}"
             MouseUp="favImage_MouseUp">
        [...]
      </Image>
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</Border>
```

The Converter:

```
public class BoolImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
     bool m = (bool)value;
     if (m)
     {
       return new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Resources/TrayPopup/bookmark_orange.png",UriKind.Relative));
     }
     return new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Resources/TrayPopup/bookmark_gray.png", UriKind.Relative));
  }
  [...]
}
```

The code behind:

```
private void favImage_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  if ([...])
  {
    ((Kollege)favImage.DataContext).Markiert = !((Kollege)favImage.DataContext).Markiert;
    lbFavs.ItemsSource = favColleagueList;
  }
}
```

Why isn't the `SourceUpdated` for my `Image` triggered and how can I solve this?

Comment: Does the `Markiert` property raise a property change notification? Take a look at the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

Comment: @Clemens: thats exactly what I was missing. though I did the exactly same thing in another class, but did oversee it this time.